# Getting Issue with print method in double Linked list code in java

Tags: java, list, double

I am writing a very simple Double Linked List code in java and everything is okay.
but when i want to print variables it prints null.
I tried and converted object to primitive data type but it isn't working

Node.java

```
public class Node {

Object data;
Node next,prev;

public Node()
{
    next=null;
    prev=null;
}


public Node(Object d)
{
    data=d;
    next=null;
    prev=null;

}

public Node(Object d , Node n, Node p)
{
    data=d;
    next=n;
    prev=p;
}
}
```

List.java

```
public class List {

Node head;

public List()
{
    head=null;
}

public void insert(Node x)
{
    x.next=head;
    if(head!=null)
    {
        head.prev=x;
    }
    head=x;
    x.prev=null;
}

public Node search(Object k)
{
    Node x=head;
    while (x!=null && !x.data.equals(k))
    {
        x=x.next;

    }
     return x;
}

public void delete(Node x)
{
    if (x.prev!=null)
    {
        x.prev.next=x.next;
    }

    else 
    {
        head=x.next;
    }

    if (x.next!=null)
    {
        x.next.prev=x.prev;

    }
}


public void print()
{
    for (Node i=head; i!=null; i=i.next)
    {
        System.out.println(i.data + " ");
    }
}
}
```

MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    List t=new List();
    Node a=new Node((Integer)(10));
    Node b=new Node((Integer)(50));
    Node r=new Node("Hello World" + " ");

    t.insert(a);
    t.insert(b);
    t.insert(r);
    t.print();
    t.delete(r);
    t.print();

    if(t.search(r)!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(" Node Found ");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(" Node not Found ");
    }


}

}
```

I am getting the 
    'null'

instead of,

```
 10 50 Hello world 10 50
```

Please Help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot print `null` with the posted code.

Also, it should print either `Node Found` or `Node not Found`.

Maybe you are executing another code?

Comment: I know but it does! I don't know why ?

Comment: Try debugging the `insert` method, to see what is receiving, if it is modifying properly the node and if the head is set to the correct value. To ease debugging, you can add a `toString` method to Node to print the data and its prev and next values.